# The preimage of maximal ideal is maximal for commutative rings with identity that sends 1 to 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So suppose $\varphi \colon R \to S$ is a homomorphism among commutative rings with identities $1_R$ and $1_S$.

The preimage of a maximal ideal may not be maximal. (If we assume $\varphi$ is surjective, then this would be true).

However, if we assume that $\varphi \colon R\to S$ is a homomorphism of commutative rings, with identities, where $\varphi(1_R) = 1_S$. Given $M \subset S$ is an maximal ideal, can we prove that $\varphi^{-1}(M)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$?

I know that $\varphi^{-1}(M)$ is a proper ideal in $R$, how do I proceed? or maybe there is a counter example?

Comment: Consider the inclusion morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$. What are the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @AlexWertheim So since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, the only ideal is $\{0\}$ and itself, then $\{0\}$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand, $\{0\}$ is not a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks for your counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is false. A very simple counterexample:

Consider a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in a commutative ring with unit $R$, and the localisation $S=R_{\mathfrak p}$ of $R$ a  $\mathfrak p$. Then $\mathfrak pS$ is the unique maximal ideal of $S$, yet $\mathfrak p$ can be chosen to be a non-maximal prime of $R$.

What is true is that the preimage of a prime ideal of $S$ is a prime ideal of $R$.